# Question about norms and seminorms

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(\mathsf{X},\mathcal{X})$ be a measurable space, $\mathcal{F}_b(X)$ be the space of bounded measurable functions, and define the supremum norm as $\Vert f \Vert_{\infty} = \sup\{ f(x) : x \in \mathsf{X}\}$ (absolute value?).

Why is 
$$
\sup_{(x,x') \in \mathsf{X} \times \mathsf{X}}|f(x) - f(x')| = 2\inf_{c \in \mathbb{R}}\Vert f - c \Vert_{\infty}?
$$

The left hand side is the oscillation seminorm, and it seems like it's the peak minus the trough of $f$, while the right hand side seems like it should be $-\infty$ or $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only correct if you define the supremum norm with the absolute value: $||f||_\infty := \sup |f(x)|$.

Then, for $b=(\sup(f)+\inf(f))/2$, and $g(x)=f(x)-b$, we have
$$\sup(g(x))=\frac{\sup(f(x))-\inf(f(x))}{2} \qquad \text{and}\qquad \inf(g(x))=\frac{\inf(f(x))-\sup(f(x))}{2}.$$

Thus,

\begin{align*}
2||g||_\infty=|\sup(f(x))-\inf(f(x))|=\sup_{(x,x')\in X\times X} |f(x)-f(x')|.
\end{align*}

This gives one inequality

\begin{align*}
\sup_{(x,x')\in X\times X} |f(x)-f(x')|\geq 2\inf_{c\in \mathbb{R}}||f-c||_\infty.
\end{align*}

Now, you can use similar ideas to show equality must hold.

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clearer. The logic is like this: first we take a particular value of $c$ (now I've called it $b$) that makes the two expressions equal. Therefore, when we take the infimum over all possibilities for $c$, the right hand side must be $\leq$ the left hand side, because the infimum is a lower bound. To get equality, we must show the value $c=b$ is "best possible," meaning that for  any $c\in \mathbb{R}$, $||f-c||_\infty \geq ||f-b||_\infty$.

Comment: The intuition is that this particular value $b$ is chosen so that $f-b$ is vertically centered over the $x$-axis. Shifting it further, up or down will either increase the supremum or decrease the infimum of the shifted function, respectively.